# Exit from imported script in python

Tags: python

`abc.py`:

```
import xyz
#also import other required modules
#other required code
xyz.func()
#other required code
```

`xyz.py`:

```
import threading
import sys
#few threads
def func():

    #start all threads
    threads.start()
    threads.join(timeout)
    #if not joined within given time, terminate all threads and exit from xyz.py
    if (threads.isAlive()):
        sys.exit()
#I used sys.exit() but it is not working for me.What else can I do here? `
```

I have a python script abc.py that imports another python script xyz.py.
I am using sys.exit() function in xyz.py. Problem I am facing here is when sys.exit() function is executed in xyz.py file, my main file i.e. abc.py also gets terminated. I don't want this to happen. My file abc.py should remain ON even though xyz.py file terminates. Is there any way to achieve this? I will be grateful to receive any help/guidance.I am using python 2.6.6 on centos 6.5.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that xyz.py is in a same type is *module* and *script*. There is common construct `if __name__ == '__main__'` that allow to separate *script* part in xyz.py from *module* part. More information here: [What does `if __name__ == “__main__”:` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Also, you misunderstanding how `import` works. There is no such thing as termination of abc.py or xyz.py, there is single interpreter which maintains global namespace containing abc.py objects. When interpreter meets `import xyz` statement it simply adds name `xyz` to namespace and to build its content, it interprets statements in that file. When it meets `sys.exit(0)` it executes it thus exiting interpreter itself.

May be you need to keep both files as a scripts and keep interpreters separate? Then instead of importing, use `subprocess.call`, i.e:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'xyz.py'])
```

Comment: how to call a function of xyz.py file here in abc.py using subprocess? I have edited my question above and included my code's format if you could please check it once

Comment: @BhoomikaSheth, myaut is correct. Your function should not be calling `sys.exit`. Have it return a value and have the caller decide whether to exit. Worst case catch the `SystemExit` exception within `abc.py` but that would constitute an egregious hack